# Haskell FFI c2hs Linking Error

Tags: c, haskell, linker, ffi

### Purpose and Setup

**Goal:** I am attemting to use the [Haskell FFI](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FFI_cook_book) to make bindings to the [Fastest Fourier Transform in the South library](http://anthonix.com/ffts/).

To do that I have elected to use the tool [c2hs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/C2hs) to help write the bindings for me. The file that I am attempting to wrap is called [ffts.h](https://github.com/robertmassaioli/ffts/blob/ff09544ffe7967cf63fc15cc8f0ff7be5c8f144b/include/ffts.h). The core of that file is the following functions:

```
#define POSITIVE_SIGN 1
#define NEGATIVE_SIGN -1

struct _ffts_plan_t;
typedef struct _ffts_plan_t ffts_plan_t;

ffts_plan_t *ffts_init_1d(size_t N, int sign);
ffts_plan_t *ffts_init_2d(size_t N1, size_t N2, int sign);
ffts_plan_t *ffts_init_nd(int rank, size_t *Ns, int sign);

// For real transforms, sign == -1 implies a real-to-complex forwards tranform,
// and sign == 1 implies a complex-to-real backwards transform
// The output of a real-to-complex transform is N/2+1 complex numbers, where the
// redundant outputs have been omitted.
ffts_plan_t *ffts_init_1d_real(size_t N, int sign);
ffts_plan_t *ffts_init_2d_real(size_t N1, size_t N2, int sign);
ffts_plan_t *ffts_init_nd_real(int rank, size_t *Ns, int sign);

void ffts_execute(ffts_plan_t * , const void *input, void *output);
void ffts_free(ffts_plan_t *);
```

As you can see there are only 8 functions, one struct that is always referred to by a pointer to it and two defines. Pretty simple.

I wrote a wrapping for those functions that you can [find here](https://bitbucket.org/robertmassaioli/haffts/src/59e40d7433ae831f45b945f0520c5210b64b746f/src/FFTS.chs?at=master). I then [used Cabal's configuration](https://bitbucket.org/robertmassaioli/haffts/src/02c5157d149b5ddda56abc83513998bac6966dc3/haffts.cabal?at=master#cl-52) to ensure that the file would be compiled correctly.

### The Problem

At this point in time I tried to start writing HUnit test cases for the FFTS library so that I could ensure that it was working as expected.
But when I compiled the code I got the following errors in the final stages of linking the test-ffts TestSuite:

```
Linking dist/dist-sandbox-c6bcbb0c/build/test-fftsStub/test-fftsStub ...
/home/robert/Projects/haffts/dist/dist-sandbox-c6bcbb0c/build/libtest-ffts.a(HUnitTests.o): In function `s3l6_info':
(.text+0x418): undefined reference to `testzmfftszm0zi1zi0zi0_FFTS_fftsFree_closure'
/home/robert/Projects/haffts/dist/dist-sandbox-c6bcbb0c/build/libtest-ffts.a(HUnitTests.o): In function `s3l3_info':
(.text+0x363): undefined reference to `testzmfftszm0zi1zi0zi0_FFTS_fftsExecute_info'
/home/robert/Projects/haffts/dist/dist-sandbox-c6bcbb0c/build/libtest-ffts.a(HUnitTests.o): In function `testzmfftszm0zi1zi0zi0_HUnitTests_hunitTests3_srt':
(.data+0xd0): undefined reference to `testzmfftszm0zi1zi0zi0_FFTS_fftsFree_closure'
/home/robert/Projects/haffts/dist/dist-sandbox-c6bcbb0c/build/libtest-ffts.a(HUnitTests.o): In function `testzmfftszm0zi1zi0zi0_HUnitTests_hunitTests3_srt':
(.data+0xd8): undefined reference to `testzmfftszm0zi1zi0zi0_FFTS_fftsExecute_closure'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Failed to install haffts-0.1.0.0
```

So that is odd. If this is to be believed then the linker failed because it could not find the fftsFree or fftsExecute closures. So I decided to have a look inside:

```
$ ar t dist/dist-sandbox-c6bcbb0c/build/libtest-ffts.a
FFTSTest.o
HUnitTests.o
$ nm dist/dist-sandbox-c6bcbb0c/build/libtest-ffts.a | grep fftsFree
                 U testzmfftszm0zi1zi0zi0_FFTS_fftsFree_closure
$ nm dist/dist-sandbox-c6bcbb0c/build/libtest-ffts.a | grep fftsExecute
                 U testzmfftszm0zi1zi0zi0_FFTS_fftsExecute_closure
                 U testzmfftszm0zi1zi0zi0_FFTS_fftsExecute_info
$
```

Now this seems to suggest that only the FFTSTest and HUnitTests object libraries made it into the archive and that the fftsFree and fftsExecute functions are not present.
But that is odd because they should have been provided when my "Build-depends" included the "haffts" dependency.

At this point in time I am not sure what I am doing wrong that is causing this error. I could really use some help with this problem and any suggestions in the right 
direction would be greatly appreciated.

**My question is this: how do I fix this error message and make it link correctly?**

### Reproducing the problem yourself

Also, if you wish to reproduce the problem yourself:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/robertmassaioli/haffts.git
cd haffts
git co -b problem-branch 02c5157d149b5ddda56abc83513998bac6966dc3
cabal sandbox init
cabal install --enable-tests
```

And you should run into exactly the same problem.

Comment: This is weird. It seems that adding the original library in the Other-Modules section of the test case did the trick. It seems that it wants to compile it again for the test cases. That seems weird to me. Why can it not reuse the one it has already built? If anybody understands why then can you answer that one please? Cheers.